# In-App purchase says submit binary to test implementation but App itself does not allow in-app purchase to be linked

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

- I Implemented and test in-app purchase successfully with Sandox
- When I submit, in-app purchase for review, it gets returned with "Developer Action Needed" and following message

> In order to approve your your new in-app purchase business model, we
>   have to verify the purchasability of the items being sold. Please
>   upload a new binary and make sure that your new in-app purchase
>   products are available for purchase at the time of review.

But when I try to upload a binary, it does show any option to choose in-app purchases.

I did remove couple of binaries from review. Not sure if that affected anything.

Now, iTunes connect does not allow me to create a brand new version from scratch.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You need to submit your IAPs for review in iTunesConnect.  As long as they are pending review when you submit your binary for review it will work.

Comment: @Paulw11 my  IAPs for review says "Developer Action Needed". I assume that would mean "Pending Review" as per your answer.

Comment: No, they need you to submit a binary that knows about these IAPs for review.  You don't need to create a new version, just increment the build number.

Comment: Ok I did that already. I only had red localization icon on the IAP page. But to me text looks fine. As Per other SO posts, I added a dot in the end and saved. Now it again says "Waiting for Review." I have submitted a binary that knows abt IAP. I just couldn't explicitly choose a IAP on App Info page. I do remember seeing it first time. But now I dont see it. If I miss something, then IAP status says "Missing Metadata"

Comment: You need to submit the new build for review at the same time as you submit the IAPs for review (not literally the same instant as they are separate actions in iTunesConnect, but as long as you have both your new app build and the IAPs in the review queue at the same time it should be OK).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably if you have tested with sandbox account then, there is no issue in your implementation. So you don't need to upload new binary, you just have to provide one sandbox account with credentials and verify once in your Features tab, of iTunesconnect about all products which have created for IAP are marked as cleared for Sale and also verify all necessary metadata are provided correctly.